# Laravel: rules request to look up in database-attribute has to be set as Y

Tags: laravel, build, request, rules

After sending the data of a formula the input values will be checked first by the defined rules.
After this a input value will be checked if it is in the database and if its attribute is set as 'Y'.

How can I define that in the formula rules request?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this behaviour you should implement a custom validator.
For example the code may look like:

```
\Validator::extend('validator1', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    //do some logic here
    // return true or false
});

\Validator::extend('validator2', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return \DB::table('table')->where('field1', $value)->where('field2', 'Y')->exists();
});

$validationRules = [
    'field'   => 'validator1|validator2'
];
```

Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules